# Export Images Stored where?

Tags: qgis, export

Where do images that are exported thru "Project - Import/Export Export map to image get stored?

Comment: After you pressed save it should have prompt you fora  location, did it not?

Comment: If you can't remember where you saved the last project image, all you have to do is export another image and make a note of the filepath. It will usually default to the last location you saved to.